# my raspberry pi wont boot

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

I have a raspberry pi 4 I flashed an sd card with ubuntu server 18.0.4 arm image but it wont boot. there is no image on my tv. I have tried both raspberry imager and etcher and both write to sd card. I have tried editing network -config with my wifi details but when I scan with nmap my other machines show up but my does not. please help.

Comment: What do you see on the LED-States when the Pi is switched on? The green led should start blinking wildly after a few seconds.

Comment: it turns red and just stays red

Comment: What adapter are you using? Sounds like it doesn't get enough juice.

Comment: It is a uk 230v motorola phone adapter with a usb port. It says its output is 5v.

Comment: @JohnBradshaw: Check that its output is also 15W(atts) or 3A(mperes). All USB power supplys have 5V(olts) as output, but the maximum power is relevant.

Comment: Two things - verify the downloaded file checksum is correct and get a proper power supply.  Chargers can output fluctuating voltage (as small dropouts) as current draw increases and a decent supply would have saved me three weeks of issues.  Current capability is as vital as stable voltage.  RPT does not sell supplies for fun but to give decent service :-)

Comment: This is a Duplicate. Edit your original Question and include the missing details. NOTE the Red PWR LED on the later model Pi **DOES NOT** indicate good power - it ONLY works with code in the kernel (although no one knows what the Canonical kernel does). Buy a proper **Power Supply**. CHARGERS are NOT Power Supplies.